# setState delay in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a function in react native which does the following:

```
resetThenSet = (id, arrayId, title) => {
    if(arrayId != 'selectProduct') {
            // Setting state for each selected dropdown in selectedDropdowns
             this.setState({
               dataShowingToggle: true,
               selectedDropdowns: {...this.state.selectedDropdowns, [arrayId]: title}
             }, this.getProductCost(arrayId, id)
           );
}
```

I run the above and I can confirm arrayId and title variables are valid and contain data.  arrayId is also not 'selectProduct'.  I added a console.log in there while debugging to ensure it runs, which it indeed does.  The expected behavior I would expect is that the state is updated immediately.

However the selectedDropdowns isn't updated in state.  When I add:
console.log(this.state) after the this.setState update there is no change.  If I run the function twice it'll update on the second time it runs.

To test it even further I added static inputs like so:

```
this.setState({
           dataShowingToggle: true,
           selectedDropdowns: {...this.state.selectedDropdowns, testField: 'me here'}
         }, this.getProductCost(arrayId, id)
       );
       console.log(this.state);
```

It only update state AFTER the first time it runs.  Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
I updated the code to run the console.log on the call back to setstate:

```
  if(arrayId != 'selectProduct') {
    // Setting state for each selected dropdown in selectedDropdowns
    console.log(arrayId + title);
    console.log('i run');
     this.setState({
       dataShowingToggle: true,
       selectedDropdowns: {...this.state.selectedDropdowns, [arrayId]: title}
     }, console.log(this.state)
   );
  };
```

console.log is 'quantityProduct 25' for the arrayId + title
console.log(I run) 
and then this state is NOT showing the quantityProduct 25

Comment: What does `this.getProductCost` do? That function will get called when your state mutation "request" completes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous. This is why the function call has an optional callback.

I think you might have other issues.

Try putting that console log inside the callback function when you call `setState` to see when the state is updated with the values you gave it.

Comment: I updated the console.log is now as the callback function and it still doesn't show updated state.  @Aaron

Comment: @FabricioG No you didn't, callbacks need to evaluate to functions, your callback is the return value of your console.log.

Comment: Ah my bad sorry fixing @Aaron

Comment: @FabricioG I'm not Aaron, and i don't know if he needs fixing :)

Comment: Lol, I'm messing up everywhere today!  @DaveNewton

Comment: Lol. I appreciate any fixing I can get. Lord knows I need it! @FabricioG, you're all good. Sounds like you got the `setState` callback working, no?